# ICommand dependency property not getting initialised

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a UserControl called `LoginControl` where I have defined a `Command`:

```
//This is LoginControl
public ICommand LoginCommand
{
    get { return (ICommand)GetValue(LoginCommandProperty); }
    set { SetValue(LoginCommandProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty LoginCommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("LoginCommand", 
                                    typeof(ICommand), 
                                    typeof(LoginControl));
```

I have a button in the `LoginControl` where the Click event calls this event handler:

```
private void Login_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    LoginCommand.Execute(passwordBox.Password);
}
```

Now I have another UserControl called `SettingsControl` where I have included the `LoginControl`:

```
<local:LoginControl Grid.Row="1" Margin="5" LoginCommand="{Binding MyCommand}"/>
```

The DataContext of the `SettingsControl` is set to itself : `DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}`
`SettingsControl` is defined like this:

```
public partial class SettingsControl : UserControl
{
    public SettingsControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MyCommand = new RelayCommand(o => MessageBox.Show("YESSS!"));
    }

    public ICommand MyCommand { get; set; }
}
```

When the `Login_Click` event handler is called, the code throws a NullReferenceException (`MyCommand` is null). I don't understand why. The `MyCommand` is initialised as you can see here. When I am initialising the `LoginControl`, I pass the `MyCommand` to it. So I don't understand why it should be null.

Comment: Did you try to initialize MyCommand before InitializeComponent? All Bindings are created in this method. Because your MyCommand property does not notify control about it value changes, you get null.

Comment: Yes, I tried initialising it before InitialiseComponent but it still throws the NullReferenceException.

Comment: Have you tried turning your MyCommand into a full property and raising OnPropertyChanged when setting it? I believe you're getting a null reference exception since the binding is not aware of MyCommand being set.

Comment: Yes, I have done everything. But still getting the exception :/

Comment: I have found the answer :) If you have any knowledge about why my answer is working, please tell me.

Answer (score 1):

After like 2 hours thinking, I have found the solution.
Move `MyCommand` initialisation above `InitializeComponent` (Thanks to [@Spawn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1979354/spawn) for the suggestion)
Give a name to `SettingsControl` in xaml. Then change the `LoginCommand` binding as follows:

```
{Binding MyCommand, ElementName=settingControl}
```

And this worked. I am guessing the previous binding was looking for the *DataContext* of the `LoginControl` itself. By specifying the ElementName, wpf knows what *DataContext* I wanted (i.e. the DataContext of the `SettingsControl`).

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful.